# sudzc generates bad soap request

Tags: objective-c

I used sudzc to access web services. However the jboss server side didn't like the soap message generated by sudzc. I suspect that this issue is about namespace... Have anybody exprienced this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and was able to fix it by removing the default namespace (xmlns=) altogether and search/replacing all method names, adding an explicit namespace as prefix
to all names.

Answer (score 1):

The main differences I see is Sudzc not including an empty header, and uses different namespaces such as soap instead of soapenv as well as set the default namespace of the document. I have no experience with JBoss but it may not be able to handle these differences (although I would think it would) but you can first try including an empty header. [SudzC is open source](http://code.google.com/p/sudzc/) if you want to check out what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Check the response from web service. Then modify the source code according to the response error. Check this post as an example.
[sudzC SOAP web service namespace problem](http://situee.blogspot.com/2013/04/sudzc-soap-web-service-namespace-problem.html)